# Error: No result was returned from some part of this expression. (-2763)

Tags: applescript, osascript

Getting the following error when running my Applescript:

348:532: execution error: No result was returned from some part of this expression. (-2763)

The applescript runs successfully when utilized within a python script and there are no issues.  But this error always is kicked back whenever the scipt executes and I would like to fix it.  I have tried inserting an extra return statement into the if/else clause, but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

```
    script="""
        try
            tell application "Finder" to get application file id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
            set appExists to true
        on error
            set appExists to false
        end try
        if appExists then
            tell application id "com.adobe.Photoshop"
                (activate) & (do javascript file "%s" with arguments {"%s", "%s"})
            end tell
        else
            return "Couldn't find proper version of Photoshop CC to launch!"
        end if
    """ % (script_path, src_files, self.path_to_folder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have PhotoShop to test, but I'm pretty sure it is from the line with the `do javascript` statement.  The term `activate` is a command to activate the application (and doesn’t return a result), while the ampersand (**&**) is used to concatenate strings, so you are trying to add a non-existent value to the javascript result.

It looks like you are wanting to use multiple statements on one line - you can’t do that with AppleScript (although in this case there isn't s syntax error), you need to put statements on separate lines.

Comment: Thanks!  This did it when I put both on separate lines.  I also needed to throw in a return afterwards, or else an undefined was always given.